# Firestore, Flutter, Async: Method not waiting for async method to finish

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm building a Flutter app that uses an API to fetch cryptocurrency prices. I stored my API Key in a Firestore database and I am currently able to retrieve the API Key from Firestore to use in my app. The problem I'm having is that when `buildURL()` is ran it doesn't wait for `String apiKey = await getApiKey();` to completely finish before continuing on, resulting in `apiKey` to be printed as Null from `buildURL()`.

I added print statements inside of `getApiKey()` and `buildURL()` to track the value of `apiKey` and it seems that the print statements from `buildURL()` are ran before the print statements from `getApiKey()`.

```
I/flutter ( 2810): Api Key from buildURL():
I/flutter ( 2810): null
I/flutter ( 2810): Api Key from getApiKey():
I/flutter ( 2810): 123456789
```

---

```
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class URLBuilder {
  URLBuilder(this.cryptoCurrency, this.currency, this.periodValue);

  String cryptoCurrency;
  String currency;
  String periodValue;

  String _pricesAndTimesURL;
  String get pricesAndTimesURL => _pricesAndTimesURL;

  getApiKey() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("myCollection")
        .doc("myDocument")
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      print("Api Key from getApiKey():");
      print(value.data()["Key"]);
      return value.data()["Key"];
    });
  }

  buildURL() async {
    String apiKey = await getApiKey();
    _pricesAndTimesURL =
        'XXXXX/XXXXX/$cryptoCurrency$currency/ohlc?periods=$periodValue&apikey=$apiKey';
    print("Api Key from buildURL():");
    print(apiKey);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning from you getApiKey function

```
getApiKey() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("myCollection")
        .doc("myDocument")
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      print("Api Key from getApiKey():");
      print(value.data()["Key"]);
      return value.data()["Key"];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to await a function it needs to be an async function.
Adding `async` and `await` to `getApiKey()` is needed to await the function.

```
 Future<String> getApiKey() async {
    var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("myCollection")
        .doc("myDocument")
        .get();
    return result.data()["Key"]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind to try

```
  Future<String> getApiKey() async {
  String result=await  FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("myCollection")
        .doc("myDocument")
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      print("Api Key from getApiKey():");
      print(value.data()["Key"]);
      return value.data()["Key"];
    });
   return result;
  }
```